# OpenFL - Android/iOS local notifications

Tags: android, ios, haxe, openfl

Developing an app in OpenFL (in Haxe), I would like to leave notifications in the status bar of Android and iOS devices at certain times.

Could someone advise me on the best way to achieve this?

Comment: For iOS you cant leave notifications in the status bar, you would use local/push notifications and/or set a badge number over your app icon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension https://github.com/josuigoa/Notifications (currently only for Android)